# Geometric progression exercise

Tags: geometric-progressions

I have this statement:

> Three numbers add up $155$ and its product is $15625$,
>
> ¿What are the terms?

I tried this:

Ok, three numbers add up $155$ is:

$a_k + a_k * r + a_k * r^2 = 155$

And, its product is 15625:

$a_k * a_k * r * a_k*r^2 = 15625$, i will divide by $r$ both sides.

$\frac{a_k}{r} * a_k * a_k * r = \frac{15625}{r}$

$(a_k)^3 = \frac{15625}{r}$

$a_k = 25* r^(\frac{1}{3})$

Then i replace in the first ecuacion of add up $155$:

$25* r^(\frac{1}{3}) + 25* r^(\frac{4}{3}) + 25 * r^(\frac{7}{3}) = 155$

Here, I did not know what to do, maybe I'm wrong at the beginning, but it's been trying for a while and I'm already confused, what's my mistake?

Comment: $\frac{a_k}{r} * a_k * a_k * r = \frac{15625}{r}$ should be $\frac{a_k}{r} * a_k * a_k * r = \frac{15625}{r^3}$

Comment: why should be that?

Comment: $(a)(ar)(ar^2)=15625$ implies that $(\frac{a}{r})(\frac{ar}{r})(\frac{ar^2}{r})=\frac{15625}{r\cdot r\cdot r}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a_k(a_kr)(a_kr^2)=15625$ $\implies$ $a_k^3r^3=15625$ $\implies$ $a_kr=25$

$$\frac{25}{r}+25+25r=155$$